# Why the function is not returning the value but printing the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return

See this function:-

```
def beej(v):
    v = sum(map(int, list(str(v))))
    if len(str(v)) <=1:
        print("printed: {}".format(v))  
        return v
    beej(v)

#outputs
>>> beej(23)
printed: 5
5                # returned
>>> beej(4221)
printed: 9
9                # returned
>>> beej(422199)
printed: 9       #no returned value
>>> beej(999)
printed: 9       #no returned value
```

So; its simply working for some values; and not for others. I'd like to know the reason behind this; and how to find such hidden bugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return statement in the recursive call:

```
def beej(v):
    v = sum(map(int, list(str(v))))
    if len(str(v)) <= 1:
        print("printed: {}".format(v))  
        return v
    return beej(v)
```

Your current code will only return `v` if the first call to `beej` (ie no recursive calls) produces a single-digit sum.

Comment: then why for some values, it does return the value?

Comment: @Vicrobot Take a moment to think about it while considering the amount of the digits of the sum in cases where it returns compared to when it does not

Comment: Thanks ! Got that.